# How to flush print statement to Button in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, game-development, tic-tac-toe, flush

I am making a simple tic tac toe game and I want to immediately print the X's and O's when a player presses a button.
Just like how you could flush a print statement and immediately have the buffer empty itself without having to go through the whole program.

```java
    // method to print X's and O's on buttons
    private void setText(Button btn) {

        if (btn.getText().toString().equals("")) { // if button NOT toggled yet
            if (state == 0) { // print 0 on button
                btn.setText("0");
                moves++;
                state = 1;
            } else { // print X on button
                btn.setText("X");
                moves++;
                state = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"when player presses on button"_ You'll need an `OnClickListener` on each button then: [https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/button](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/button)